# Accepting Variable and Using It as a Function

Tags: php, function, variables

So, I'm trying to turn a variable into a function.

```
$go_menu=$_POST['menu'];
$go_menu();

Function potoato_chip()
{
    echo "I like Doritos!";
}

Function apples()
{
    echo "I like Fuji";
}
```

I am getting the data from the `$go_menu=$_POST['menu']` but everything below `$go_menu();` comes up blank.

The full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/7zrJAsc9) in a pastebin.  Appreciate any help!  I'm still learning!

Comment: Calling arbitrary functions from `$_POST` is generally a bad idea. Consider filtering?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php Use this please.

Comment: if i where to guess you had a function called delete() ...

Comment: You can also constrain the permissible functions by packing them into a class, and invoking them as static methods instead `menu_funcs::$go_menu();`.

Comment: oh this is very wrong, Doritos are not made from potatoes, they are corn based ;-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure it's callable before calling it:

   ```
   $go_menu = $_POST['menu'];

   if(is_callable($go_menu))
       $go_menu();
   ```
2. Keep an array of valid values; this will fix both your "no content" problem *and* your security problem:

   ```
   $valid_actions = array('potato_chip', 'apples');

   if(isset($_POST['menu']) && in_array($go_menu = $_POST['menu'], $valid_actions)) {
       $go_menu();
   }
   ```

Comment: Awesome!  Appreciate it!  Lemme give it a try.

Comment: I tried the is_callable...there was an error...I don't know what the error was...but I switched to a switch case.  Thanks @minitech!

Comment: @Softwaretech: Did you try the second one? That should definitely work. But anyway, make sure to accept the answer that you ended up going with. If you used a `switch`, I guess that would be Richard Ye's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this: it's highly insecure to execute a variable as a function when you just got that value from a POST! In particular because you're creating an admin interface. Any malicious person could execute other functions in your code if needed.

You should use if statements or a switch statement to control what needs to happen.

Note that `Function` should be written as `function` in PHP.

Comment: @zerkms: Well, it's my answer so I did. @minitech: Fair enough, I've always known PHP with `function` but `Function` indeed works.

Comment: so does "FunCtiOn" if you are one of those *special* people that type like that

Comment: @Simeon Visser: "should be" is definitely wrong words. It shouldn't be, it's all about particular project Coding Convention and 146% irrelevant to the question

Comment: @zerkms: I think you're confusing that with the percentage of statistics that are made up (and it's actually closer to 147%). `;)`

Comment: @minitech: it's local Russian meme, related to former president elections. http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Flurkmore.to%2F%25D0%25A7%25D1%2583%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%23.D0.A0.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B0_.C2.AB146.25.C2.BB --- the second part started with "In the live coverage" it is the whole history PS: and sorry for google translate, cannot find any native english articles

Comment: @minitech: well, here it is - http://gawker.com/5864945/putin-clings-to-victory-as-russias-voter-turnout-exceeds-146

Comment: Stay on Target, Luke, Stay on Target.

Comment: LOVE the feedback!  I love the my brother and/or sister coders are watching out for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, your code is incredibly insecure. Let's say I edit your form and submit a `POST` request setting `$_POST['menu']` to, let's say `die`. This crashes your program. You can just imagine what else I can do with this. A correct way to do this would be with `switch`:

```
switch $_POST['menu'] {
    case "menu_1":
        menu_1();
        break;
    case "menu_2":
        menu_1();
        break;
    [...]
}
```

Generally speaking, I don't like to use variable variables or variable functions, because it's hard to keep track of the possible values of a variable. However, they can still be used if there are properly validated, like in minitech's answer. In your case though, since you seem to have a limited selection of functions that can be called, I would use `switch`.

Comment: PS, actually, the example I gave with `die` isn't true, because `die` is a construct, not a function, and therefore can't be called using variable functions. The point of not validating your call still stands, though, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I think switch case will be better.  The site has some security and is coming from an admin site.  I opened it a little for review and advisement.  I'm going to "switch" it up a bit :)